# Typescript Private or protected member 'something' cannot be accessed on a type parameter

Tags: typescript, class, oop, this, typescript-typings

```js
class SomeClass<T extends string> {
  protected someMethod(): void {

  }

  protected someOtherMethod(): ReturnType<this["someMethod"]> { 
  // Private or protected member 'someMethod' cannot be accessed on a type parameter.ts(4105)


  }
}
```

Is there any way to reference back the type of protected class member in the class itself?

Answer (score 4):

This can easily solved by using the class name instead of `this`:

```
class SomeClass {
  protected someMethod(): void {

  }

  protected someOtherMethod(): ReturnType<SomeClass["someMethod"]> { 

  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKD2BbApgYXFaBvAUNaADgE7wAuyw5AJtBEsgLLKkAW8VAFAJQBc0AbvACWNXHmgBfHOOJkK1WvQDyrZESat23PgCVmAVyIA7ACoBPAsgA8CFOkgQA2gCI6KDWyrOAugD5s0NL4UhJAA)

Comment: Here's a thing.. The class has some generic params, if I use your way, then I have to insert the generic again `ReturnType<SomeClass<A,B>["someMethod"]>`, I'm trying to save that effort

Comment: And the class name keep floating around will make it more complicated..